# Mongo find query always returns empty result for field that exists

Tags: mongodb

For no reason which I don't understand I can not query a particular field in a documents

I have a collection called `orders` 
When I run:

```
db.orders.find({}).pretty();
```

I get the result below:

```
{
    "_id": "585bc54ee5652c1e4a59a4c5",
    "item": "Milk",
    "amount": "20.0",
    "user": "585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb"
},
{
    "_id": "585bc54ee5652c1e4a55532ba",
    "item": "Vanilla",
    "amount": "10.0",
    "user": "585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb"
},
{
    "_id": "585bc54ee5652cbab3837b333",
    "item": "Chocolate",
    "amount": "15.0",
    "user": "585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb"
}
```

So now I have issue selecting orders that belongs to a certain user with user id
`585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb` 
The record exists but empty is always returned

```
db.orders.find({"user":"585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb"}); --> returns {}
```

The query above returns empty. Please what could be the cause?

Comment: are you using any tool? or is it happening on mongo shell?

Comment: Have you tried `db.orders.find({"user": ObjectId("585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb") });`?

Comment: no. I didn't yet try that. will try now and revert

Comment: @chridam works!!! wow. I'm fairly new to Mongo. Please why must I add ObjectId() and can this work from nodejs? using aggregate `$match: {user: "ObjectId('1334444')"}`

Comment: This means the `_id`s you are getting are the string representation of the `ObjectId()`. Documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). If you're using Node.js: `var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId; var o_id = new ObjectId("585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb"); db.orders.find({_id: o_id})` as well as the `$match` pipeline.

Comment: @chridam works like charm. Thanks a million. Please could you post your response as answer so i can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the id with **[`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)** as it's a string representation of it:

```
db.orders.find({"user": ObjectId("585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb")
```

---

If you're using Node.j then the following should suffice:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId, 
    o_id = new ObjectId("585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb"),
    collection = db.collection('orders'); 

collection.find({_id: o_id}).toArray((err, orders) => console.log(orders));
```

or is using aggregate method:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId, 
    o_id = new ObjectId("585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb"),
    collection = db.collection('orders');

collection.aggregate([ { "$match": { "_id": o_id } } ], (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Great answer.

Comment: I'm aggravated by how unclear these things are from the documentation (or just not there).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.orders.find({user : "585bc154e5652c1e4a59a4bb"});
```

user can or cannot be enclosed within quotes. For me, it is working for both the cases.

Comment: Thanks @Nikita Mantri but I have tried already and doesn't work